# From Layout to StaticLayout: How can I use StaticLayout instead of a simple layout to draw multiline texts?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have been working in an app that let the user takes a photo and then let him put a text over it. This is working perfect when the user types a small phrase. 
This is my code:

```
enter code here
private Bitmap ProcessingBitmap(String captionString) {
    Bitmap bm1;
    Bitmap newBitmap = null;
    try {         
        bm1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(pickedImage));

        //create an empty bitmap
        newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm1.getWidth(), bm1.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        //create a new Canvas object and pass this bitmap to it
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newBitmap);

        canvas.drawBitmap(bm1, 0, 0, null);
        Paint paintText = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

        paintText.setColor(Color.RED);
        paintText.setTextSize(convertDpToPixel(50,this));
        paintText.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        paintText.breakText(captionString,true, canvas.getWidth(),null);
        paintText.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paintText.setTypeface(Typeface.create("Sans", Typeface.BOLD));

        Rect textRect = new Rect();
        paintText.getTextBounds(captionString, 0, captionString.length(), textRect);

        if(textRect.width() >= (canvas.getWidth() - 4))
            paintText.setTextSize(convertDpToPixel(25,this));

        int xPos = (canvas.getWidth() / 2);
        int yPos = (int) ((canvas.getHeight() / 2) - ((paintText.descent() + paintText.ascent()) / 2)) ;

        //Draw Canvas
        canvas.drawText(captionString, xPos, yPos, paintText);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return newBitmap;
}
```

**However, when the user types a long phrase it goes out of the photo area!**

I looked online and found a lot of information about StaticLayout. Like this one: http://ivankocijan.xyz/android-drawing-multiline-text-on-canvas/

So I tried to use it in my code but I do not know what I am doing wrong! It is not working when I use a StaticLayout Canvas.

Is there a easy way to convert this code to a staticLayout? Is there another consideration that I am missing?

I lost one week trying to solve it and nothing worked so far. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution, it was easier than I thought! Here it goes! Hopefully it will help someone someday!

```
private Bitmap ProcessingBitmap(String captionString) {
    Bitmap bm1;
    Bitmap newBitmap = null;
    try {
        //Decode image
        bm1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(pickedImage));

        //create an empty bitmap
        newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm1.getWidth(), bm1.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        //create a new Canvas object and pass this bitmap to it
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newBitmap);

        //pass bitmap to canvas
        canvas.drawBitmap(bm1, 0, 0, null);

        //Create and configure text
        TextPaint mTextPaint = new TextPaint();
        mTextPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(convertDpToPixel(100,this));
        mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        mTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mTextPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mTextPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.create("Sans", Typeface.BOLD));

        //StaticLayout
        StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(captionString, mTextPaint, canvas.getWidth(), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1, 1, true);

        //Draw Canvas
        int xPos = (canvas.getWidth() / 2);
        int yPos = (int) ((canvas.getHeight() / 2) - ((mTextPaint.descent() + mTextPaint.ascent()) / 2)) ;
        canvas.translate(xPos, yPos);

        //Draw Canvas
        layout.draw(canvas);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return newBitmap;
}
```